# Model from sketchfab not animating in aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

Link

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/internal-electric-shear

I downloaded the unicorn from sketchfab and converted blender file to .glb. For some reason, animation mixer is not triggering the animation. I tried putting my glb file in other online viewers and they run fine there. The animation I am looking for is called Run but nothing is working.

Comment: I have one suggestion alone to the way you are asking question here. The best way is to add the important lines of code here and attach glitch link so people would be able to help you easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation-mixer you used is not a default feature of a-frame. It's a part of aframe extras by donmccurdy

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
```

also use correct name in animation mixer attribute exactly same as mentioned in sketchfab website

```
<a-entity  gltf-model="./unicorn.gltf" animation-mixer="clip:walk">
```